# Proof verification: Prove $A\cup B = B\cup A$ and $A\cap B=B\cap A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify whether my following proofs are logically correct? :) I am not sure how to go about these proofs, so I just guessed.

$A\cup B=B\cup A$

Proof: Let $x\in A\cup B$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. Then $x\in B$ or $x\in A$. Then $x\in B \cup A$. Then $A\cup B \subset B\cup A$.

Let $x\in B\cup A$. Then $x\in B$ or $x\in A$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. Then $x\in A \cup B$. Then $B\cup A \subset A\cup B$. Therefore, $A\cup B=B\cup A$. $\square$

$A\cap B=B\cap A$

Proof: Let $x\in A\cap B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Then $x\in B$ and $x\in A$. Then $x\in B \cap A$. Then $A\cap B \subset B\cap A$.

Let $x\in B\cap A$. Then $x\in B$ and $x\in A$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Then $x\in A \cap B$. Then $B\cap A \subset A\cap B$. Therefore, $A\cap B=B\cap A$. $\square$

Comment: These look fine to me.

Comment: These are fine, but they could be shortened by half by using "Iff" in place of each "Then" to take care of both directions simultaneously.  $x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A$ or $x\in B\iff x\in B$ or $x\in A\iff x\in B\cup A$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand what you mean. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct and well-presented. Good job!

The one nitpick I have would be in the style; it feels a little repetitive/monotonous to keep saying "then [...]. Then [...]. Then [...]." I would either do this proof as a sort of bulleted list, where the implications are obvious ...

> - Assume $x \in A \cup B$.
> - Thus, $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.
> - Equivalently, $x \in B$ or $x \in A$.
> - Therefore, $x \in B \cup A$.
> - Therefore, $A \cup B \subseteq B \cup A$.

... or perhaps purely symbolically, as

> $$\begin{align}
> A \cup B = B \cup A &\implies A \cup B \subseteq B \cup A \\
> x \in A \cup B &\iff x \in A \text{ or } x \in B \\
> &\iff x \in B \text{ or } x \in A \\
> &\iff x \in B \cup A \\
> \end{align}$$
> $$\therefore A \cup B \subseteq B \cup A$$

Both are a bit less grinding to read. Personally, I prefer the first, since words are useful and important in proofs. The second would be okay if everything is clear and unambiguous, but I can see it being problematic for a novice reader of proofs to see what the purpose of the above is.

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*